# Passing data to UICollectionReusableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am using custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout, and i have registered custom reusable class for this layout...

```
 [self registerClass:[noContentDecoration class] forDecorationViewOfKind:knoContentsDecorationKind];
```

Now, i want to pass some data to this decoration view in the initialization phase, i want to set some properties in this reusable class

But i can't reach this view, I only found this delegate method for UICollectionView:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingSupplementaryView:(UICollectionReusableView *)view forElementOfKind:(NSString *)elementKind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

but the problem here: this method invoked only when the reusable view is removed as mentioned in the documentation:

> Use this method to detect when a supplementary view is removed from a collection view, as opposed to monitoring the view itself to see when it appears or disappears.

what i can do to pass data to this reusable view in the initialization ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a decoration view.  Passing data to it is complicated.

1. Create a custom subclass of `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` to hold the data.
2. In your `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass, override `layoutAttributesClass` to return your custom attributes class.
3. Also in your `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass, set the attributes for the decoration view properly in both `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` and `layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:atIndexPath:`.
4. In your decoration view class (`noContentDecoration`), override `applyLayoutAttributes:` to pull the data out of the attributes object and apply them.

Does that seem too complicated?  Perhaps you would be better off using a supplementary view instead of a decoration view.  If you use a supplementary view instead, the steps are:

1. In your `UICollectionViewDataSource` (which is probably your view controller), implement `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:` to get a view (using `dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:`), then set it up with the data, then return it.

I recommend using a supplementary view instead of a decoration view if you need to customize it with data from your model.